# Jbutton disappears in design view

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

I'm using WindowBuilder in Eclipse. I Created the following method to apply the same properties to certain types of buttons in my application.

In design view, my btn_Subscribe is invisible, but it appears when debugging. 
However my btn_Login is visible in design view... I don't get it. I'm using my method when I add the JButton to the content

```
    // ************************ LOGIN BUTTON ************************ \\

JButton btn_Login = new JButton("");
btn_Login.setIcon(new ImageIcon(DietProject.class.getResource("/images/img_login.png")));
btn_Login.setBounds(226, 89, 91, 32);

frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(setupCustomButton(btn_Login));
// ************************ SUBSCRIBE BUTTON ************************ \\

JButton btn_Subscribe = new JButton("");
btn_Subscribe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
});
btn_Subscribe.setIcon(new ImageIcon(DietProject.class.getResource("/images/img_subscribe.png")));
btn_Subscribe.setBounds(10, 11, 103, 32);
frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(setupCustomButton(btn_Subscribe));








private JButton setupCustomButton(JButton jb)
{
    // Remove the ugly border and background on the button
    jb.setBorderPainted(false);
    jb.setBorder(null);
    jb.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    jb.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    return jb;
}
```

Comment: Is it only the problem with editor or the button doesnt show up in the output frame also ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by output frame. It wont show up in the editor/design view, but when I run the application it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `frmDietPlanner` is a `JFrame`  which has by default  `BorderLayout` manager.  
By

```
frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(setupCustomButton(btn_Login));
frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(setupCustomButton(btn_Subscribe));
```

You are adding two buttons to the same location. 
If you want to use `setBounds` set layout manager to null.

An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem and the solution looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    Frame()
    {
        /////////////////////////////
        setLayout(null);
        ////////////////////////////
        setSize(400,400);
        JButton btn_Login = new JButton("A");
        btn_Login.setBounds(226, 89, 91, 32);
        getContentPane().add(btn_Login);

        JButton btn_Subscribe = new JButton("B");
        btn_Subscribe.setBounds(10, 11, 103, 32);
        getContentPane().add(btn_Subscribe);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, now how would you suggest I apply the properties to those buttons that I want without having to copy and paste it for each and every single one? I've got about 12 more buttons to do...

Comment: use `setupCustomButton` as you did. It is fine. Just irrelevant to the problem you raised. [MCVE] help you focus on the problem and helps those who try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I do the following, it shows up in the designer just fine. I don't get why using a method to apply the same properties would cause the designer not to display the button.... and at the same time it works perfectly fine for my login button! I really don't feel like doing this code for every single button I plan on using....

```
//frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(setupCustomButton(btn_Subscribe));
frmDietPlanner.getContentPane().add(btn_Subscribe);
btn_Subscribe.setBorderPainted(false);
btn_Subscribe.setBorder(null);
btn_Subscribe.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btn_Subscribe.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

Comment: This is a good example why you should always post an [MCVE]. Those properties and `setupCustomButton` are irrelevant.